# How can i add subtitles to the video showing in my Web Application like courser and khan academy , i use Vimeo player to hosting my videos

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I am working on Web Application  (it is classroom )   and I need to show the subtitles under the video like Coursra , when the user starts the video the pointer go and select the subtitles

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use Video.js

[VideoJS](https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/text-tracks.html)